# Android tv box for dolby vision and lossless audio formats passthrough

Tags: android, hdtv, set-top-box

What can you recommend for playing video files with dolby vision?
Also it should support the passthrough of all the lossless audio formats through HDMI (Dolby TrueHD, DTS-MA, atmos).
I would like to keep the budget for this at <del>70 eur</del> 150 EUR.

Currently I use H96 max x3 box with CoreELEC, but it can't output dolby vision. The tv I'm using is LG C1. I like the minimalistic approach of the CoreELEC software, but I'm willing to adapt if some other combination of software brings more supported formats. And for the sake of more options - any other software is welcome in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CoreELEC only few devices supports DV and they cost twice of your budget (around 150 €).

Supported devices: Dune/Homatics R 4K Plus, Nokia 8010, RockTek G2.

More information: https://discourse.coreelec.org/t/coreelec-and-dolby-vision/20982

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer. Actually I already bought the Dune R 4K Plus, awaiting its arrival. But I would like to know if these devices have any competitors, will edit the question to increase the budget and lower the focus to CoreELEC.

Comment: Accepting this answer, because I'm using the Dune version of this device myself and can confirm that dolby vision works using CoreELEC, also Dolby TrueHD and DTS-MA passthrough.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is cheaper alternative:
BOXY with Dune HD Media Center, ~100 €
https://www.dune-hd.com/products/boxy

It is on the way to CoreELEC developers.

Update: This device is locked and not possible to run CoreELEC on it.

Comment: Thanks again, are you a Dune device user? I'll soon be able to check that for myself, but do you think CoreELEC or the Dune media center is more advanced / more comfortable to use for local video file playing? By reading the descriptions, I like that Dune media center supports ISO files and folders, with menus, if I understand that correctly. But also I don't see DTS MA listed in bitstream passthrough formats, so CoreELEC has the advantage here.